# Popup form to edit shape position and label?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to click on a shape to edit its text label and x,y coordinates using a popup form that, when submitted, updates the data for that shape and the shape then moves to the new x, y coordinates.  I've been unable to find any examples like this online or in the usual books.

Data for all shapes on the page is stored in a JSON array. Some online examples show how to edit text "in place" or edit a single value. This will not work for me, since only the label should be displayed on the shape and I want to edit multiple shape parameters not usually visible on the page.

I would like to keep the solution as D3 or basic JavaScript, if possible.

A simple example showing three clickable rectangles is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/NovasTaylor/oyL0hj3d/

The current `"click"` event writes the label, x and y values to the console. This event should trigger the display of the editable form.

```
rects.append("rect")
  .attr("x",     function (d)  { return d.x; })
  .attr("y",     function (d)  { return d.y; })
  .attr("height", function (d) { return d.height; })
  .attr("width",  function (d) { return d.width; })
  .style("fill",  function(d)  { return d.color; })
  .on("click", function(d){
    console.log("You clicked rectangle: " + d.label)
    console.log ("X position: " + d.x)
    console.log ("Y position: " + d.y)
  });
```

All advice greatly appreciated and working example even more so!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In D3 it's quite simple to override the datum. Inside the listener where `d` is the first parameter, just do:

```
d.foo = bar;
```

In your example, let's use `prompt` to get the new values. This is just a demo to show you how to do it: you can easily change the ugly prompts for fancy popup divs.

So, inside the listener, we get the new values...

```
var newLabel = prompt("Please enter the new label: ");
var newX = prompt("Please enter the new x position: ");
var newY = prompt("Please enter the new y position: ");
```

... and use them to reposition the rectangles, overriding the datum at the same time:

```
d3.select(this)
    .attr("x", d.x = +newX)
    .attr("y", d.y = +newY);
```

The only problem is getting the labels. As you have to go up and down in the DOM, I suggest you to give them (unique) ids...

```
rects.append("text")
    .attr("id", function(d, i) {
        return "label" + i;
    })
```

... and them getting them:

```
d3.select(this.parentNode)
    .select("#label" + i)
    .text(newLabel)
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.x + 10;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return d.y + 10;
    });
```

Here is your code with those changes only:

```js
var rectData = [{
  "label": "one",
  "x": 100,
  "y": 50,
  "height": 100,
  "width": 120,
  "color": "green"
}, {
  "label": "two",
  "x": 250,
  "y": 50,
  "height": 100,
  "width": 120,
  "color": "purple"
}, {
  "label": "three",
  "x": 400,
  "y": 50,
  "height": 100,
  "width": 120,
  "color": "red"
}];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 600)
  .attr("height", 200);

var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(rectData)
  .enter();

rects.append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return d.height;
  })
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return d.width;
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return d.color;
  })
  .on('mouseover', function(d) {
    var rectSelection = d3.select(this)
      .style({
        opacity: '0.5'
      })
  })
  .on('mouseout', function(d) {
    var rectSelection = d3.select(this)
      .style({
        opacity: '1'
      })
  })
  .on("click", function(d, i) {
    var newLabel = prompt("Please enter the new label: ")
    var newX = prompt("Please enter the new x position: ")
    var newY = prompt("Please enter the new y position: ")
    d3.select(this).attr("x", d.x = +newX).attr("y", d.y = +newY);
    d3.select(this.parentNode).select("#label" + i).text(newLabel).attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.x + 10;
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return d.y + 10;
      })
  });

// Rectangle Label
rects.append("text")
  .attr("id", function(d, i) {
    return "label" + i;
  })
  .style("fill", "black")
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.x + 10;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.y + 10;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return "Label: " + d.label
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Have in mind that this is a very, very simple demo: I'm neither checking the type of the input (string, integer, float...) nor their values.

PS: If you were using D3 v4 (that, with your code, requires **no change** at all!), you could avoid the new-positioned rectangle going behind the other ones with a simple `selection.raise()`.

Comment: Thanks Gerardo. Sequential update of the values is a step in the right direction. I should have added more detail in the original post: How can the initial (current) values of label, x, and y be displayed together in the same editable form?  Users need to see the original values and may only wish to update only one, two, all three, or none of the values. Is this a job for foreignObject or jQuery forms?

Comment: Please, don't edit your original question: asking **several** different questions here at S.O. is *"too broad"*. I showed you how to change the DOM elements and the data with D3. Regarding the "form", you don't need one, and you don't need `foreignObject` as well: a simple div with inputs can do the job. I suggest you posting a *new* question, asking how to do it.

Comment: Thank you. I will do as you suggest. I am still learning proper S.O etiquette. Your advice is very helpful.

Comment: @Tim It's very simple: if you ask a specific, narrow problem, people will help you. However, if your question has 3 or 4 different issues (in this case: 1. how to get the values, 2. how to create a popup div, 3. how to show the values; 4. how to get the new inputs; 5. how to update the elements), people will, rightfully, close your question as too broad. Try to break up your problem into *different* questions.