# Updating data values with HTML input and changing the data array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to update a shape's label, x position, and y position values that are displayed in a `<div>` when the shape is clicked. 
https://jsfiddle.net/NovasTaylor/q8cLhw9b/

The user edits the form fields to change values as desired, then clicks commit to write the changes (if any) back to the JSON array.

I built the form within the rectangle's `"click"` event which also triggers opacity to show the form in the `<div>` at the top of the page:

```
.on("click", function(d){
  d3.select("#rectInfo").style("opacity", 1);

  var infoForm = d3.select("#rectInfo").append("form")
   .attr("id", "foo")
   .attr("action", "javascript:submitForm();")
   .attr("method", "post")
   .attr("class", "formEle");
```

The display works as desired. However, I do not know how to push the values from the form back to the JSON array. The submitForm() function merely clears the div convent.

```
function submitForm(){
  d3.selectAll(".formEle").remove();
  d3.select("#rectInfo").style("opacity", 0);
}
```

How do I get the values from the form back into the JSON array?

Comment: Why are you using a form? Are you going to send this data to somewhere else? It seems to me that you just want to change the loaded data... if that's correct, you should not use a form.

Comment: You are correct. I just want to update the data and it does not need to be a form. The data stays within the page. In my previous post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47481625/popup-form-to-edit-shape-position-and-label) you stated my question was too broad so I  further developed my example to create the <div> and show the values in editable fields the only way I know how: using a form (I'm an old guy - think PERL CGI!) . I am very open to other methods that display all 3 parameters at once in the div for edit, then push back into the array and have the div content disappear from view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47520054/shape-parameters-updated-from-html-form-back-to-source-json-array#comment82144895_47520054), you are not sending this information to anywhere. Therefore, you don't need a form.

So, just append regular text inputs to that div...

```
var div = d3.select("#rectInfo")

var labelText = div.append("p")
    .text("Label: ");

var labelInput = labelText.append("input")
    .attr("size", "15")
    .attr("type", "text")
    .attr("value", d.label);

var xPosText = div.append("p")
    .text("X pos: ");

var xPosInput = xPosText.append("input")
    .attr("size", "15")
    .attr("type", "text")
    .attr("value", d.x);

var yPosText = div.append("p")
    .text("Y pos: ");

var yPosInput = yPosText.append("input")
    .attr("size", "15")
    .attr("type", "text")
    .attr("value", d.y);
```

... and create a button that, on "click", gets the values of the inputs and changes the `x`, `y` and `label` properties:

```
var button = div.append("button")
    .text("Submit/Hide")
    .on("click", function() {
        d3.select(self).attr("x", function(d) {
            return d.x = +xPosInput.node().value
        }).attr("y", function(d) {
            return d.y = +yPosInput.node().value
        });
        d3.select("#text" + i).text(function(d) {
                return "Label: " + (d.label = labelInput.node().value);
            })
            .attr("x", function(d) {
                return d.x = +xPosInput.node().value + 10
            }).attr("y", function(d) {
                return d.y = +yPosInput.node().value + 10
            });
    })
```

Pay attention to this pattern:

```
return d.x = +xPosInput.node().value
```

It does two things:

1. It returns a value (in this case, `+xPosInput.node().value`);
2. It assigns that value to `d.x`, therefore changing our datum.

Also, the input returns a **string**, even if the user types a number... that's why there is a unary plus operator before `xPosInput.node().value` in the example above.

As a final note, I'm not a fan of removing/re-appending elements (I'm talking about the div). You could simply updated them. However, as I told you in my other answer, this is a *different* issue and here at S.O. we try to keep just one issue per question (so, I'm not dealing with it in this answer).

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
var rectInfoActive = false;
var rectData = [{
  "label": "one",
  "x": 100,
  "y": 50,
  "height": 100,
  "width": 120,
  "color": "green"
}, {
  "label": "two",
  "x": 250,
  "y": 50,
  "height": 100,
  "width": 120,
  "color": "purple"
}, {
  "label": "three",
  "x": 400,
  "y": 50,
  "height": 100,
  "width": 120,
  "color": "red"
}];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 600)
  .attr("height", 200);

var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(rectData)
  .enter()
  .append("g");

rects.append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return d.height;
  })
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return d.width;
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return d.color;
  })
  .on('mouseover', function(d) {
    var rectSelection = d3.select(this)
      .style({
        opacity: '0.5'
      })
  })
  .on('mouseout', function(d) {
    var rectSelection = d3.select(this)
      .style({
        opacity: '1'
      })
  })
  .on("click", function(d, i) {

    var self = this;

    if (rectInfoActive == true) {
      // clicked a node while previous info block displayed
      d3.selectAll("input").remove();
      d3.selectAll(".formEle").remove();
      d3.select("#rectInfo").selectAll("*").remove();
      d3.select("#rectInfo").style("opacity", 0);
    }

    d3.select("#rectInfo").style("opacity", 1);

    // Form displayed in /div becomes visible onclick of a rect.
    // submit button clears the form. No data update yet.
    var div = d3.select("#rectInfo")

    var labelText = div.append("p")
      .text("Label: ");

    var labelInput = labelText.append("input")
      .attr("size", "15")
      .attr("type", "text")
      .attr("value", d.label);

    var xPosText = div.append("p")
      .text("X pos: ");

    var xPosInput = xPosText.append("input")
      .attr("size", "15")
      .attr("type", "text")
      .attr("value", d.x);

    var yPosText = div.append("p")
      .text("Y pos: ");

    var yPosInput = yPosText.append("input")
      .attr("size", "15")
      .attr("type", "text")
      .attr("value", d.y);

    var button = div.append("button")
      .text("Submit/Hide")
      .on("click", function() {
        d3.select(self).attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.x = +xPosInput.node().value
        }).attr("y", function(d) {
          return d.y = +yPosInput.node().value
        });
        d3.select("#text" + i).text(function(d) {
            return "Label: " + (d.label = labelInput.node().value);
          })
          .attr("x", function(d) {
            return d.x = +xPosInput.node().value + 10
          }).attr("y", function(d) {
            return d.y = +yPosInput.node().value + 10
          });

        d3.select("#rectInfo").selectAll("*").remove();
        d3.select("#rectInfo").style("opacity", 0);
      })

    rectInfoActive = true;



  });
// END OF FORM

// Rectangle Label
rects.append("text")
  .attr("id", function(d, i) {
    return "text" + i
  })
  .style("fill", "black")
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.x + 10;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.y + 10;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return "Label: " + d.label
  });



// Misc functions -------------------------------------------------------------
// clearTheForm ----
// Clear the form and input values. This will later become the Update function
//  that will update changed values back into the JSON array.
```

```css
#rectInfo {
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 230px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px;
  outline: grey solid thin;
}

#rectInfo p {
  margin: 4px;
}

.formLabel {
  font-family: courier;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Click on a shape to see its label, x, y pos.
  Submit button clears the div (not working here in fiddle)
  but should be changed to instead call a fnt that updates the data with values changed in the form.
-->

<div id="rectInfo" style="opacity:0">
  <!-- Rect info will appear here -->
</div>
```